# double check locking in singleton pattern

Tags: c#

it may be basic question

to have a singleton in multi-threaded environment we can use a lock.  Please refer the code snippet. But why do we need double-checked locking in singleton pattern? And more what does double-checked locking means?

```
class singleton
{
    private static singleton instance = null;
    private static singleton() { }

    private static object objectlock = new object();

    public static singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {

            lock (objectlock) //single - check lock
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new singleton();
                }

                return instance;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx is in fact all you need to know. I was about to post the same when two others beat me to it. That should speak volumes for its worth.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Jon Skeet [explains this in detail](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx).

Locks are expensive.
If the object already exists, there's no point in taking out a lock.
Thus, you have a first check outside the lock.

However, even if the object didn't exist before you took the look, another thread may have created it between the `if` condition and the `lock` statement.
Therefore, you need to check again inside the lock.

However, the best way to write a singleton is to use a `static` constructor:

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private Singleton()
    {
    }

    public static Singleton Instance { get { return Nested.instance; } }

    private class Nested
    {
        // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
        // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
        static Nested()
        {
        }

        internal static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();
    }
}
```

Comment: in the link given - // Bad code! Do not use!
Third version - attempted thread-safety using double-check locking

Comment: @Raghav55: What do you mean? I can't see a third version in this answer.

Comment: @Raghav: This isn't the third version.  Did you mean to comment on @TcKs' answer?

Comment: sorry i didn't provide the link : http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: @Raghav: I know; I just quoted that.  However, I'm using his fifth version.

Comment: i justed wanted to know why he was written bad code do not use

Comment: Can somebody explain to me the mechanics of how using the static constructor makes the Singleton threadsafe without using locks. Thanks

Comment: @sc_ray: The CLR locks for you before running the initializer.

Comment: I found a reason for not using this solution; if an exception occurs your client will see the exception nested in a TypeInitializationException which will make it less obvious. Hence I revert back to double check locking solution  (Jon Skeet solution 3)

Answer (score 6):

Multithreaded Singleton : The best approach to use double check locking

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
   private static volatile Singleton _instance;
   private static readonly object InstanceLoker= new Object();

   private Singleton() {}

   public static Singleton Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         if (_instance == null) 
         {
            lock (InstanceLoker) 
            {
               if (_instance == null) 
                  _instance = new Singleton();
            }
         }

         return _instance;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

And with .Net 4.x and newer you should defer to the Lazy class when possible as this pattern is used with the Initialization And Publication option. (note: the inverse is available as well where creation isn't thread safe but the publication of the instance is via the Publication option)

Answer (score 4):

The "best" way I know is this:

```
public class MySingleton {
    // object for synchronization
    private static readonly object syncRoot = new object();
    // the singleton instance
    private static MySingleton @default;

    public static MySingleton Default {
        get {
            // geting singleton instance without locking
            var result = @default;
            // if result is NOT null, no additional action is required
            if ( object.ReferenceEquals(result, null) ){
                // lock the synchronization object
                lock(syncRoot) {
                    // geting singleton instanc in lock - because
                    // the value of @default field could be changed
                    result = @default;

                    // checking for NULL
                    if ( object.ReferenceEquals(result, null) ) {
                        // if result is NULL, create new singleton instance
                        result = new MySingleton();
                        // set the default instance
                        @default = result;
                    }
                }
            }

            // return singleton instance
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is really the best way you know, I suggest you read the provided link.

Comment: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx.  This is unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: It's the same implementation as the "Third version - attempted thread-safety using double-check locking".

Comment: No; you have extra checks.  Once you're in the lock, you don't need to swap.  Also, he recommends against the third version.

Comment: @SLack: there are 2 checks - like in link. Because between "var result= @default;" and "lock(syncRoot)" can another thread initialize the singleton value.

Comment: @TcKS: As @SLaks already said: It is not the same as the third version. Although it is quite close, you still should read the link thorougly, because there are better ways to implement a singleton.

Comment: @TcKs: You're right; I misread.  However, there is no point in the `@default` field.

Comment: @SLacks: Do you mean "@default" or "result" field? If you want, you can skip the "result" variable. But the final generated code will be same because of value (reference) from "@default" field to the stack of method.

Answer (score 3):

If you create the object in the field initialiser, you don't need the lock:

```
class singleton
{
    private static singleton instance = new singleton();
    private static singleton() { }

    public static singleton Instance
    {
        get { return instance; }
    }
}
```

Also - bear in mind that the lock is only controlling the creation of the object, the object would still need to be thread-safe if you're using it in multiple threads.

Answer (score 2):

When we try to execute the method of the singleton class using Parallel libraries. It doesn’t recognize the singleton behavior because of multi threading is executing in TPL which causes to failure of concept Singleton Pattern . To overcome this problem there is concept of the locking of the object so that at a time only one thread can access it.
But this is not efficient approach because involvement of lock checking creates unnecessary watches to the object. To avoid it we make use “Double locking checking”

[image]